# Debug mode is not working with jhipster in STS Eclipse

Tags: debugging, spring-boot, breakpoints, jhipster, spring-tool-suite

I'm working with JHipster 4.9.0 and STS Eclipse 3.9.0 (Spring Boot 1.5.7).

The problem is that I'm not able to debug because an error.

When I try by clicking "Debug As" ---> "Spring Boot App" I get this:

```
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\user1\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\f346404c3876c5bd0e07a7e10b7565bdcd35dbab\liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: C:\Users\user1\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\f346404c3876c5bd0e07a7e10b7565bdcd35dbab\lib\snakeyaml-1.13.jar

        ??? ???   ??? ????????? ????????   ??????? ????????? ????????? ????????
        ??? ???   ??? ????????? ????????? ???????? ????????? ????????? ?????????
        ??? ?????????    ???    ????????? ???????     ???    ???????   ?????????
  ???   ??? ?????????    ???    ????????   ???????    ???    ???????   ????????
  ????????? ???   ??? ????????? ???       ????????    ???    ????????? ???  ????
   ???????  ???   ??? ????????? ???       ???????     ???    ????????? ???   ???

:: JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 1.5.7.RELEASE ::
:: http://www.jhipster.tech ::

2017-10-06 15:39:16.338  WARN 8540 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/config/prosopografia/dev/master": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2017-10-06 15:39:16.366  INFO 8540 --- [  restartedMain] a.g.i.prosopografia.ProsopografiaApp     : The following profiles are active: swagger,dev
2017-10-06 15:39:22.246  INFO 8540 --- [  restartedMain] a.g.i.p.config.WebConfigurer             : Web application configuration, using profiles: swagger
2017-10-06 15:39:22.251  INFO 8540 --- [  restartedMain] a.g.i.p.config.WebConfigurer             : Web application fully configured
2017-10-06 15:39:22.492  WARN 8540 --- [afia-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2017-10-06 15:39:37.682  WARN 8540 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ambitoServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\Desarrollo\prosopografia\bin\a\g\i\prosopografia\service\impl\AmbitoServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'a.g.i.prosopografia.service.mapper.AmbitoMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2017-10-06 15:39:37.995 ERROR 8540 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in a.g.i.prosopografia.service.impl.AmbitoServiceImpl required a bean of type 'a.g.i.prosopografia.service.mapper.AmbitoMapper' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'a.g.i.prosopografia.service.mapper.AmbitoMapper' in your configuration.
```

If I run the command "gradlew" or the task "bootRun" of "Gradle Tasks" it work perfect, but I can't debug, because I can't use breakpoints.

What can be the problem?

Comment: I don't use Eclipse so can't hep with it but you cane debug either running the `main()` of your app as a launch target or using `gradle bootRun --debug-jvm`.

Comment: "What can be the problem?"
Very hard to say. Maybe jhipster adds some gradle magic to how things run and naturally STS/eclipse will not be aware of any extra magics added to the gradle run. Another potential explanation is that test dependencies added to the runtime classpath mess things up. This has been a long standing problem with gradle eclipse integration that only recently BuildShip folks have started to fix.

Comment: For some background on the classpath issue that *might* play a role in this. See: https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/354 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=482315

Comment: Thanks Gaël Marziou, that works perfect