# how to start jhipster backend in debug mode?

Tags: jhipster

I'm working with `JHipster 5.3.0` and `STS` `Eclipse 3.9.4`.

I need to start jhipster backend in debug mode, but I cannot find how. [Another question like this has no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612330/debug-mode-is-not-working-with-jhipster-in-sts-eclipse) but things may have changed, so I ask it again.

When I do:

> gradle bootRun --debug-jvm

it does not finish. It stays at `90%` so login fails.

Thanks

Comment: I don't use Eclipse but I usually prefer to create a run target that runs the application main class, it starts faster than launching maven or gradle and debugging si easy.

Comment: I followed https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-java-local-configuration.htm  instructions, but it does not start even when I click the Resume (F8) a million times.

Comment: Did you select the same class as in mainClassName  in your biuld.gradle ?